# When does $(ab)^c = e \; \Rightarrow \;a^c = b^c = e$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group.  Suppose that $a, b\in G$ have finite orders $n$ and $m$, respectively, and suppose also that $ab = ba$.

Now, given these assumptions, it is clear that

$$c\in \mathbb{Z}\;\wedge \; a^c = b^c = e \;\;\; \Rightarrow \;\;\; (ab)^c = e\;.$$

In words: if an integer $c$ is such that $a^c = b^c = e$, then it follows that $(ab)^c = e$.  (The proof of this is trivial: $(ab)^c = a^c b^c = e e = e$.  Of course, I'm *not* saying that $a^c = b^c = e$ for all $c \in \mathbb{Z}$!)

Is the converse also true?  If so, I'm interested in the proof of it; if not, what are the necessary conditions for it to be true?

EDIT: OK, from the comments I see that the converse is not true in general, but, as the title says, I'm interested in the necessary conditions for the converse to be true.

Comment: Surely not? Consider $(\mathbb{Z}_8,+)$, then $4^2=4+4=0=e$, but $4=2+2$ and $2^2=4\neq0$.

Comment: Let $a=b$ and $2c=\operatorname{ord}(G)$

Answer (score 1):

Your assertion is actually incorrect.

If $G$ is an abelian group, $a \in G$ has order $m$ and $b \in G$ has order $n$ then $ab$ has order $\mathrm{lcm}(m,n)$.

So for example if $a$ has order $2$ and $b$ has order $4$ then $ab$ has order $4$, not $2$ as your assertion would suggest.

A counterexample is given for $G=\mathbb{Z}_8$ by BlackAdder in the comments, but in fact *any* two elements $a,b$ in *any* abelian group $G$ will be counterexamples so long as their orders are distinct, by taking $c$ to be the least of the two orders.

---

As for the converse, suppose $a$ and $b$ are given and that $(ab)^c = e \Rightarrow a^c=b^c=e$ for all $c \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then in particular it holds when $c=1$, so you have
$$ab=e \Rightarrow a=b=e$$
but this only holds in trivial circumstances, i.e. when $b \ne a^{-1}$ or when $a=b=e$ already. In particular, it only holds universally (for all $a$ and $b$) when $G$ is the trivial group.

Comment: @kjo: I didn't use abelianness of $G$ beyond the assumption that $ab=ba$, so feel free to replace 'abelian' with this property wherever you see it written in my answer. And 'if $c$ is such that blah then blump' is the same as saying 'for all $c$, if blah then blump', so my answer still applies. [And anyway that's *not* what you said, but even if it was it wouldn't matter!]